# Unittests for nested functions

Tags: unit-testing, go

Suppose I have some code

```
type SomeObject struct {
    user *models.User
}

func (obj *SomeObject) DoSmthLogic(val1 int, val2 int) error {
   // do step 1
   // do step 2
   // do step 3
}
```

I decided to cover this code with unittests.
Then for convenience i decided to mode steps to seprated method and cover each method.

```
type SomeObject struct {
    user *models.User
}

func (obj *SomeObject) DoSmthLogic(val1 int, val2 int) error {
   result = obj.step1()
   obj.step2(result)
   obj.step3()
}

func (obj (SomeObject) step1() int {
    // do smth
}

// the same for other steps
```

Not it's easy to cover these 3 methods.
But how can I cover `DoSmthLogic` method?

For example in Python I can easly mock `steps` methods and check in unittests if these methods were called:

```
obj.step1 = Mock()
obj.step2 = Mock()
obj.step2 = Mock()

obj.do_smth_logic()

obj.step1.assert_called_once()
obj.step2.assert_called_once()
obj.step3.assert_called_once()
```

What can you suggest for this?

Comment: In case you don't know, in Go, you can't mock concrete methods. So there is nothing like `obj.step1 = Mock()` in Go. You could turn the `step` methods into fields of type `func`, and *then* you could mock those, but, if that doesn't seem very clean to you, that's because it isn't.

Comment: I think about use interface for these steps methods.
I will be able to mock interface.
But it's a lot of code)

Comment: Well interfaces can be mocked of course, but if the `step` methods need access to the `obj` instance then, I fear, it won't be much of an improvement over `func` fields.

Comment: Yes, definitely, you can end up with having to write too much code if you distribute every single task to a separate interface *and* implementation.

Comment: "What can you suggest for this?" DoSmthLogic has 3 inputs (obj, val1 and val2) and an output and potential side effects on obj. A Go style test would test that various input combinations produce the desired result (return value and side effect). No need to mock anything.

Comment: @Volker, yes sure. But I thought about to minimize unittests code

Comment: @Mike I have to admit I do not understand you comment.

Comment: In some cases it's complicated to check all side effects.
So due to this reason I thought about separate "main" logic function and tests these

Comment: When approaching this problem I'd have to ask what we're testing if we've mocked all the dependencies? 
If we put ourselves in the position of the caller of the DoSmthLogic method what we're interested in is whether the state of the program conforms to what we expect after calling the method. 
I'd argue that tests that depend on the implementation details being a certain way are inherently fragile and will end up costing more in maintenance in the long run than any benefit they may give now... 
If I can suggest this talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZ05e7EMOLM, it opened my eyes.